# Relations are not saved when updating the model using EF4 code-first

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4, code-first, ef-code-first

Like the title says I do a successful update, but it won't save relations like user-role or whatever. It works great when I add the user (in my case) with roles and all, but update doesn't work, that's only with the relation everything else get updated. I have this problem with other objects as well. Does anyone have any idea why it won't save the relation if it's changed on update? I posted some code too, but I have a feeling it's not that important here. I think I'm just missing something simple.

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //hämta användaren och redigera parametrar
                var user = _userService.GetById(viewModel.User.Id);

                viewModel.User.Roles = user.Roles;

                //kolla språken
                if (viewModel.CultureSelected != null)
                {                    
                    foreach (var item in viewModel.CultureSelected)
                    {                        
                        viewModel.User.LanguageCultures.Add(_languageCultureService.GetById(item));                        
                    }
                }

                //updatera och spara
                TryUpdateModel(user, "User");
                _userService.Save();

                ViewData[Message] = "";
                return RedirectToAction("Lista");
            }
```

**EDIT**

In this case, I ended up adding the `Languagecultures` to the `user` directly instead of the `viewmodel.user`:

```
public ActionResult Redigera(AdminUserAddViewModel viewModel)
        {
            //kolla om state är valid
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //hämta användaren och redigera parametrar
                var user = _userService.GetById(viewModel.User.Id);                

                //kolla språken
                if (viewModel.CultureSelected != null)
                {                    
                    foreach (var item in viewModel.CultureSelected)
                    {                        
                        user.LanguageCultures.Add(_languageCultureService.GetById(item));
                    }
                }

                //updatera och spara
                TryUpdateModel(user, "User");
                _userService.Save();

                ViewData[Message] = "";
                return RedirectToAction("Lista");
            }

            viewModel.CultureSelectList = CutlureSelectList(_languageCultureService.GetAll());
            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm still MVC beginner but I think that `TryUpdateModel(user, "User")` looks only for HTTP post values prefixed by "`User.`" string. Also I think it uses directly posted data, not your viewModel instance.